# Data being passed from UITableView to new Controller, SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I've been at this for a while and I can not figure out how to pass data from the table view cell to a new "detail" controller. I understand the segue that connects it to a new controller but setting variables in that class to some values fails (doesn't show the values). This is what I currently have:

```
import UIKit

class BuyTreeViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    var products : [Product] = []
    var filteredProducts = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

      self.products = [
        Product(name:"Chocolate", price: 11, description: "i"),
        Product(name:"Candy", price: 12, description: "h"),
        Product(name:"Break", price: 13, description: "g"),
        Product(name:"Apple", price: 14, description: "f"),
        Product(name:"Computer", price: 15, description: "e"),
        Product(name:"Laptop", price: 16, description: "d"),
        Product(name:"Cup", price: 17, description: "c"),
        Product(name:"Table", price: 18, description: "b"),
        Product(name:"Chair", price: 19, description: "a")
      ]

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
      return self.filteredProducts.count
    } else {
      return self.products.count
    }
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    var product : Product
    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Candy object from the appropriate array
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
      product = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]
    } else {
      product = products[indexPath.row]
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel!.text = product.name
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return cell
  }

  func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    self.filteredProducts = self.products.filter(
      {
        ( product : Product) -> Bool in
        var categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (product.category == scope)
        var stringMatch = product.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    })
  }

  func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    let scopes = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
    let selectedScope = scopes[self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as String
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString, scope: selectedScope)
    return true
  }

  func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!,
    shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
      let scope = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
      self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text, scope: scope[searchOption])
      return true
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("productDetail", sender: tableView)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "productDetail" {
//      let productDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
      let productDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ProductDetailViewController
        productDetailViewController.testLabel.text = "123345"

      if sender as UITableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        let indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let destinationTitle = self.filteredProducts[indexPath.row].name
        productDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
      } else {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let destinationTitle = self.products[indexPath.row].name
        productDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
      }


      productDetailViewController.productPriceText = "10"
      productDetailViewController.productTitleText = "100"
      productDetailViewController.productDescriptionText = "100"
    }
  }
```

And this is what I have in the ProductDetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var productDescription: UITextView!
  @IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var productTitle: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var connectUserButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

//  var productDescriptionText: String
//  var productPriceText: String
//  var productTitleText: String


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//        productDescription.text = productDescriptionText
//        productPrice.text = productPriceText
//        productTitle.text = productTitleText
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
  @IBAction func contactUserClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("conentUserButton clicked")
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "productDetail" {

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let theSelectedRow = filteredProducts[indexPath!.row]
        let theDestination = segue.destinationViewController as ProductDetailViewController

        theDestination.productPriceText = "10"
        theDestination.productTitleText = "100"
        theDestination.productDescriptionText = "100"

    } else

      //only needed if more than one segue
    }
}
```

Your detailViewController looked good to me.  If you still have issues, I will post a more complete example.

Comment: This line, theDestination.testLabel.text = "123345" won't work. At the time of prepareForSegue, the detail controller has been instantiated, but its view has not loaded, so its outlets will be null.

Comment: oops, fixed in a minute

Comment: Unfortunately no this did not work. I can not set the text for it since it is nil. Is there any other way to set the labels in the next view? @SteveRosenberg

Comment: Unfortunately no this did not work. I can not set the text for it since it is nil. Is there any other way to set the labels in the next view? @rdelmar

Comment: @user3698231, you can't set the text for what? Are you talking about testLabel, or all of them?

Comment: I put an example on github for you  https://github.com/StevenRoseneberg/Contacts2/tree/master   Lunch hour now.  I can help you more after work.  Let me know what you need.

Comment: Regarding testlabel, use the same syntax (no chaining with the dot syntax) to pass the data.